# ASP.NET Pipeline Not Publishing Content

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to create a new build pipeline in DevOps to build a website. The main solution is being used as the source; it contains the website project as well as a separate unit test project. The logs show the build is succeeding but the publish portion is not being run.

For the build solution step (using Visual Studio Build), I am passing in the following arguments:

`/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:DeleteExistingFiles=true`

I've run the same build arguments on my local machine using msbuild from
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`
which is putting content and respective files into the publishUrl parameter.

I've also tried using the default template without making any modifications. Default parameters are `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`
but no package is being built in this scenario.

It feels like it's completely ignoring the publish options being passed in.

The `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` has been resolving to `D:\a\1\a`.

The publish artifact step yields the following log:

`[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
[section]Finishing: Publish Artifact: drop`

Any one have some ideas or suggestions on what is going on? I'd like to know if/where I should be expecting the _PublishedWebsites folder to exist. I don't want to use a publish profile for this as I am not using Azure to do the actual deploy of the website.

Thanks!

**msbuild output**

`2019-03-29T15:51:41.2933271Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.148.1\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=89dd4c73-fcb3-42df-9dc2-04dd3a648e8f|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.148.1\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="D:\a\1\a\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:DeleteExistingFiles=true /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_f901243b-a555-4171-87b9-2b1950d52707_build_3_0"
2019-03-29T15:51:41.3709460Z Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
2019-03-29T15:51:41.4083747Z Build started 3/29/2019 3:51:41 PM.
2019-03-29T15:51:41.5914885Z Project "D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2019-03-29T15:51:41.5931469Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2019-03-29T15:51:41.5931540Z   Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
2019-03-29T15:51:41.9148684Z Project "D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi.sln" (1) is building "D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi\LoggingApi.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2019-03-29T15:51:41.9148780Z PrepareForBuild:
2019-03-29T15:51:41.9148830Z   Creating directory "bin\".
2019-03-29T15:51:47.5470138Z CoreCompile:
2019-03-29T15:51:47.5472670Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\Google.Protobuf.3.7.0\lib\net45\Google.Protobuf.dll /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\MySql.Data.8.0.15\lib\net452\MySql.Data.dll /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Configuration.Install.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Drawing.Design.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Management.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.ServiceModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Transactions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll /reference:D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Xml.dll" /debug- /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\LoggingApi.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs App_Start\WebApiExceptionFilter.cs App_Start\WebApiNullCheckActionFilter.cs Authorization\WebApiAuthorization.cs Common.cs Constants.cs Controllers\BaseController.cs Controllers\MessageController.cs Dal.cs Global.asax.cs Controllers\EventsController.cs Models\LogEntryDto.cs Models\MessageDto.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
2019-03-29T15:51:47.6084430Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9411825Z _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9412789Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\MySql.Data.8.0.15\lib\net452\MySql.Data.dll" to "bin\MySql.Data.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9413051Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\Google.Protobuf.3.7.0\lib\net45\Google.Protobuf.dll" to "bin\Google.Protobuf.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9413271Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" to "bin\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9415018Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to "bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9442165Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" to "bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9442252Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Http.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9442305Z   Copying file from "D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9460232Z   Creating "D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi\obj\Release\LoggingApi.csproj.CopyComplete" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9479340Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9479432Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\LoggingApi.dll" to "bin\LoggingApi.dll".
2019-03-29T15:52:08.9484851Z   LoggingApi -> D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi\bin\LoggingApi.dll
2019-03-29T15:52:09.1237828Z CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToOutputDirectory:`

[roslyn stuff here]

`2019-03-29T15:52:09.1587962Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\LoggingApi\LoggingApi.csproj" (default targets).`

Comment: What does the MSBuild output look like?

Comment: @DanielMann Won't let me put the full msbuild logging output in. Any specific section you're looking for?

Comment: The section where it packages the binaries. Also, note that `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true`. Are you sure the platform/configuration are valid?

Comment: @DanielMann I used the same parameters on my local build to test that. Didn't have an problems locally. Updating the main post; will leave out the roslyn section.

Comment: @DanielMann ran another test removing the `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true`; still no files being published.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> ASP.NET Pipeline Not Publishing Content

Since the project type is web site and you do not want to use a publish profile, you can try following method:

After creating a publish profile in VS the following are created:

1) A publish profile (.pubxml file) under App_Data/PublishProfiles

2) A **website.publishproj** in the root of the website

The purpose of the `website.publishproj` is to facilitate command line publishing. Then you can try to use **msbuild build task** like the following to publish it:

```
msbuild.exe "WebSite1\website.publishproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

And this also should be work for the first command:

```
msbuild.exe "WebSite1\website.publishproj" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:DeleteExistingFiles=true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give it a try with the publish profile but I'm looking for a method without needing it. Hopefully this will work with not the single file package as I need them all individually.

Comment: Going `Build > Publish Website` does not create a website.puhlishproj in root or anything under App_Data. Only a FolderProfile.pubxml is created in Properties > PublishProfiles.

Still looking for a way to not use profiles like I was able to with TFS2013 build definitions / solutions.